# ASP Membership Odd Problem

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle, membership

I am using the Membership API in ASP .NET and I have encountered the following problem on my staging server.  The application works fine on my local machine.  The data tables are stored on a SQL Server.  Both my local and staging server point to the same DB server.  When I deploy to my staging server I get the following error:

```
 Parser Error Message: The connection name 'OraAspNetConString' was not 
 found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty. 

    Line 135:    <roleManager>
    Line 136:      <providers>
    Line 137:        <add name="OracleRoleProvider" 

type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleRoleProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=2.111.6.20,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" 
connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" />
    Line 138:        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"   
connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" 
type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    Line 139:        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" 
applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, 
System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />


Source File: 
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config
    Line: 137
```

I do not know why it is even trying to do anything with Oracle, my `web.config` does not contain anything associated with Oracle.

Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening?

**[Edit]**
On my local machine's machine.config I do not have the OracleRoleProvider key.  But my staging server does.  If that helps.

Answer (score 7):

Old question here but I just ran into it and wanted to share some more details.

First, the easiest solution if you need to do a `<clear/>` in your connectionStrings block is to add a blank OraAspNetConString connectionstring entry back into your web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
      <add name="OraAspNetConString" connectionString=" "/>    
</connectionStrings>
```

What happens when you [install the Oracle .NET package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/e10928/IntroInstallation.htm) on any of your machines is it installs a ton of different providers into your machine.config along with the OraAspNetConString as a machine-level connectionString. The `<clear/>` element gets rid of that OraAspNetConString and thanks to Oracle's machine.config additions all of the other Oracle providers loaded by default are crashing when they can't find the connectionString.

The other answer here where you explored using the  element for membership providers didn't work because most of the other oracle providers added in the machine.config are still going to be looking for that **OraAspNetConString** so clearing just that one provider doesn't help you.

These are all the providers they installed into my machine.config:

```
<membership><providers>
    <add name="OracleMembershipProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleMembershipProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" />
</providers></membership>
<profile><providers>
    <add name="OracleProfileProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Profile.OracleProfileProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName=""/>
</providers></profile>
<roleManager><providers>
    <add name="OracleRoleProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Security.OracleRoleProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName=""/>
</providers></roleManager>
<siteMap><providers>
    <add name="OracleSiteMapProvider" type="Oracle.Web.SiteMap.OracleSiteMapProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName="" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
</providers></siteMap>
<webParts>
  <personalization>
    <providers>
      <add name="OraclePersonalizationProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Personalization.OraclePersonalizationProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" applicationName=""/>
    </providers>
  </personalization>
</webParts>
<healthMonitoring><providers>
    <add name="OracleWebEventProvider" type="Oracle.Web.Management.OracleWebEventProvider, Oracle.Web, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionStringName="OraAspNetConString" buffer="true" bufferMode="OracleNotification"/>
</providers></healthMonitoring>
```

So if you didn't want to add the blank OraAspNetConString you'd have to make sure that you either `<clear/>` every one of the following Oracle Providers or go in and add a `<remove name=x />` element to each provider class like this:

```
<membership><providers>
    <remove name="OracleMembershipProvider" />
</providers></membership>
<profile><providers>
    <remove name="OracleProfileProvider" />
</providers></profile>
<roleManager><providers>
    <remove name="OracleRoleProvider" />
</providers></roleManager>
<siteMap><providers>
    <remove name="OracleSiteMapProvider" />
</providers></siteMap>
<healthMonitoring><providers>
    <remove name="OracleWebEventProvider" />
</providers></healthMonitoring>
```

I never dealt with any siteMap or Health Monitoring code in my web app but I still had to manually add these `<remove/>` elements for the different providers in my web.config or something would crash looking for an OraAspNetConString connection string that wasn't there.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define your own provider in your config file for example here is a membership provider:

```
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MyConnection" applicationName="MyApp"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Basically this will remove all the providers defined at the system level, This is why we are clearing, then you define your new providers. If you need the providers at the system level you can define your own as the default, or in your app code specifically request your provider.

Comment: Well just add a dummy connection string called OraAspNetConString. If your sure you've removed it it shouldn't run. But this might let you continue on your way. Also make sure you did that for the RoleProvier as well as Membership

Answer (score 0):

This error is saying you have that in the machine.conf not web.config.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to find out why that oracle connection string is in the machine.config.  If you are not able to remove it then you'll need to override it.  Are you sure you have the <clear/> in your web.config which Josh mentioned?  I thought that should clear the providers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an empty ConnectionString for "OraAspNetConString" worked for me

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="OraAspNetConString" connectionString=" "/>
    .................. your other connectionstrings goes here .....
</connectionStrings>
```