# All users allowed in Web.Config, but Application still prompts for UserName/Pass?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, iis-7

So I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application I have developed with Oracle & Entity Framework. Originally I was using my LocalDB Context file for Development, and after clearing most of the bugs I setup a connection to my actual ORACLE DB tables and modified what was needed within the application to allow the same functionality I had using the LocalDB Context file.

Everything works fine on my local machine, but when I publish to the Server I was receiving

> The connection name 'OraAspNetConString' was not found in the
>   applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

I tried a few solutions mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651385/asp-membership-odd-problem) like the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <clear />
      <add name="OraAspNetConString" connectionString="RandomConnection" />
      <-- My Other Connection Strings -->
</connectionStrings>
```

Which resulted in

> The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications
>   configuration or the connection string is empty.

So I then tried:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <clear />
      <add name="OraAspNetConString" connectionString="RandomConnection" />
      <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="RandomConnection" />
      <-- My Other Connection Strings -->
</connectionStrings>
```

Which gets rid of the error, but when I try to access the application on the server I am prompted for a User Name / Pass?

Using my own credentials does not work and ends with

> **HTTP Error 401.1** - Unauthorized: You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

This makes no sense to me (nor do I understand why I'm getting prompted for UserName/Pass) as I have specified to allow all users?

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
          <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
          <authorization>
              <allow users="*"/>
              <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
```

Looking at some other threads, I removed the above modifications and tried the following:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
          <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
          <authorization>
              <allow users="*"/>
              <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
          <membership>
              <providers>
                  <remove name="OracleMemberShipProvider" />
              </providers>
          </membership>
          <roleManager>
              <providers>
                  <remove name="OracleRoleProvider" />
              </providers>
          </roleManager>
```

This resulted in the same UserName/Password prompt. I then tried:

```
  <membership>
      <providers>
          <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"/>
      </providers>
  </membership>
  <roleManager>
      <providers>
          <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

Which again resulted in

> The connection name 'OraAspNetConString' was not found int he
>   applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

Then from a different thread I tried the below again receiving the UserName/Password prompt:

```
  <membership>
      <providers>
          <clear />
      </providers>
  </membership>
  <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
          <clear />
      </providers>
  </roleManager>
  <profile>
      <providers>
          <clear />
      </providers>
  </profile>
```

Can anyone help with this? I cannot figure out why I'm being prompted for a UserName/Password when I've specified Windows Authentication and to allow all users? My Full `web.config` is below (with the first 2 attempts of clearing the connection string ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
      <clear />
      <add name="OraAspNetConString" connectionString="RandomConnection" />
      <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="RandomConnection"/>
      <add name="ProjectEntities" connectionString="CONNECTION LIFETIME=16;CONNECTION TIMEOUT=8;DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_123)(PORT=1234)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=hostid1)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));MIN POOL SIZE=3;PASSWORD=123_pass;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=SCHEMA123" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" /></connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
      <!--<add key="DefaultConnection" value="Default" />-->
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeAssembliesForScan" value="ProjectName" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!-- Active Directory Authentication - http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
      <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
          <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" /><add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" /><add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" /></httpModules>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="GridMvc" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
        <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" />
      <remove name="BundleModule" />
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" /><add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" /><add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" /></modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="ProjectName.DAL.ProjectNameContext, ProjectName">
        <databaseInitializer type="ProjectName.DAL.ProjectInitializer, ProjectName" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<elmah>
    <!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
    -->
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
  </elmah><location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->  
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1234))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

---

**UPDATE**:

The above is what I was receiving when trying to navigate to the project's published location http://project/ on the server machine. When trying to access http://project/ on my local browser I was receiving:

```
Runtime Error

Server Error in '/' Application. Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
```

After adding `<customErrors mode="Off" />` under `<system.webServer>` I receive (on my local machine browser):

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' could not be loaded.
```

Any thoughts on this? I know other applications on the same server are using `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` and are working fine, whereas for my framework version I had to use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`.

Comment: Windows Authentication always prompts for credentials, even if accessing a directory that everyone is allowed to access. I don't know of a way around that, other than switching to non-Windows authentication and authenticating against AD instead.

Comment: @mason, I think AD would work for what I'm doing here. Could you provide an example of what I need to modify to make use of AD instead of Windows Authentication?

Comment: I would expect Internet Explorer to load a web page without prompting when using Windows Authentication, if you have signed onto the network from that PC. Is that your situation? Firefox can be configured to not prompt as well, but it prompts by default.

Comment: @LonProsser, I would expect the same. When I try to load the app from it's published location `http://project/` in my Local Browser I get `Runtime Error: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.` Then when I log onto the server machine and browse to `http://project/` I receive the above listed problem of UserName/Pass prompt.

Comment: The `It could however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine` error message is a security thing. By default, actual messages are not shown to anyone accessing the site outside of the server. The underlying error though will be what you're seeing when you hit it from the server. You may need to configure Internet Explorer to give the credentials. That may be disabled for the security zone the site is in (so either adjust the security zone of the site it's in, or switch security zones). You can push that out to everyone via Group Policy, check with your system admin.

Comment: As for getting rid of Windows authentication and switching to Forms Authentication against AD, that's been answered plenty of times out there, so search the web for a good tutorial.

Comment: I believe I finally got this solved. Once I got the error message to fully show which stated `File or assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess' could not be found` I kept the `<clear /><add name="OraAspNetConString" || name="LocalSqlServer"/>` and under my References I changed the `Oracle.ManagedData. Access`, `Copy Local` property to `True`. Doing a new publish my Application now loads up as expected! Thanks for both of your help on this.